# c# wcf webservice accept json dynamic data

Tags: c#, wcf

I want my c# Webservice to accept dynamic data.

right now i am doing this

class:

```
 [DataContractFormat]
    public class person
    {

        public string name { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string age { get; set; }
    }
```

method

```
public string person(person p)
        {

            string name = p.name;
            return name;
        }



[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/person/do",
        Method = "POST",
         RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json
               )]
        string person(person p);
```

this is my json body

```
{
    "name":"",
    "address":"",
    "age":""
}
```

I don't want to define properties in the class, and I want it to accept any data I send to it. now its accepting the "name":"", "address":"", "age":" 
eg: if I want I sud be able to give date-of-birth without defining it in class. Hope you would understand

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic data?"

Comment: Can you be more specific?For example, what is dynamic data and how to pass dynamic data.

Comment: I don't want to define properties in the class, and I want if to accept any data I send to it. now it s accepting the 
"name":"",
    "address":"",
    "age":"

eg: if i want i sud be able to give date-of-birth without defining it in class.
Hope you would understand

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean.Normally, after WCF service is started, you can view its help document to view the data format received by WCF service.

```
      [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    Result PostUserData(UserData user);
```

This is the definition of WCF service interface.

```
        public class UserData
{
    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

This is the definition of UserData class,which has three properties: name, password,email.

[image]

According to your description, if we send a Josn not in the above format to the WCF service, the WCF service will receive the JSON without error.

[image]

But now there's a problem. You don't define these attributes in class. How do you receive them?You can only parse JSON to get data.Of course, you can send what you call dynamic data to the WCF service, but when you receive it, you only parse the data yourself.